# Match Pattern and write following value as variable

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed

I'm trying to match a pattern and then pull the following information to create a file using that variable.

Example  (my data may look like either of the 2 examples)

```
"headers": {
            "content-type": "application/octet-stream;\r\n\tname=\"I may have long file names - With lots of spaces.zip\"",
            "content-transfer-encoding": "base64",
            "content-disposition": "attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"I may have long file names - With lots of spaces.zip\""
```

or

```
"headers": {
            "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
            "content-transfer-encoding": "base64",
            "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=tiny.exe"
```

Basically I'm trying to create a new file named as the filename.  So example 1 has a really long filename with spaces and hypens, example 2 has a short filename.  Example 1 is identified by 'tfilename' and example 2 'filename' .

Obviously I don't need the double quotes.

Can anyone assist with this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this  JSON data?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using JQ to process the JSON.  But the problem with this particular section is that the information I'm seeking is deep within the object.  Using JQ and Grep, I got it down to this point.  So now I'm just trying to grab the filename so that I can (1) store it as a variable & (2) create a new file using that name.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a language that can parse the JSON and manipulate the data. Here's some ruby (and shell)

```
$ cat data.json 
{
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/octet-stream;\r\n\tname=\"I may have long file names - With lots of spaces.zip\"",
        "content-transfer-encoding": "base64",
        "content-disposition": "attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"I may have long file names - With lots of spaces.zip\""
    }
}

$ filename=$(ruby -rjson -e '
    data = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV.shift))
    m = data["headers"]["content-disposition"].match(/filename=(.+)$/m)
    filename = m[1].gsub(/^"|"$/,"")
    puts filename
' data.json)

$ echo "$filename"
I may have long file names - With lots of spaces.zip
```

Comment: Thats really nice, but I don't really want a ruby implementation just for this one aspect.  I'm already using jq to parse the data.  Surely there is a simple awk or sed command to pull the info.   I ended up getting this, but it's a bit janky:    cat file | jq -r '.parts[1].headers."content-disposition"' | sed -n -e '2p' | sed  s/'filename='/''/ | sed -e s/'"'/''/ | sed -e s/'"'/''/

Comment: untested, but `awk 'NR==2 {sub(/.*filename=(\\")?/,""); sub(/(\\")?"$/,""); print; exit}'` should replace all your seds

Comment: The nice thing about the ruby solution is that it takes care of all the quotes and escaped quotes. It should not be much more heavyweight than jq and whatever.